# dynamic allocation for structs and setting a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, xml-parsing

I've allocaten 5 places for a struct - where each CELL is a pointer to the struct. now I want the second cell for example to point on my struct but I get an error : expression must be a modifiable value.
I get the point that I'm relocating my pointer, but I don't understand how can I fix it without copying all the values.

here is the example i'm using : (the relevant stuff)

```
    typedef struct childrenArray
{
    PXML_ELEMENT    childrenArray;
     UINT32         numOfChildren;
     UINT32         maxNumOfChildren;
 }CHILDREN_ARR,*PCHILDREN_ARR;




 typedef struct xml_Element
 {    
     PDATA_ELEMENT           pData;
     PCHILDREN_ARR          pChildrenArr;
     PXML_ELEMENT           pParent;
     PATTR_ARR              pAttributeArr;
     UINT32                     depth;
  };
```

when I'n creating the children array :
the code is :

```
PCHILDREN_ARR retArr;
retArr->childrenArray = (PXML_ELEMENT)Calloc(retArr->maxNumOfChildren ,sizeof(XML_ELEMENT)); /*my max is 5 .. */
```

and now I get the problem : 
I want to use this function :

```
XML_STATUS xml_AddChildToEndArray(PXML_ELEMENT pChild , PXML_ELEMENT pParent)
{
     pParent->pChildrenArr->childrenArray + pParent->pChildrenArr->numOfChildren = pChild;
}
```

there I get the error ...can I get an explanation why it's wrong
and how can I fix it?

I dont want to to :

```
'currentCell ->name = pChild-> name'
```

copying all values... just to make it point on the child

thanks!

Comment: You are saying something equivalent to `n + 2 = 5;`. That makes no sense. Do you mean `n = 5 - 2;`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want to append an item to an "array" `childrenArray` in the structure `childrenArray`?

First of all you must make sure you have enough space allocated for the new array. This can be done with e.g. [`realloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbebcx7d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Maybe something like this:

```
/* Allocate space for one more entry */
pParent->pChildrenArr->childrenArray =
    realloc(pParent->pChildrenArr->childrenArray,
            (pParent->pChildrenArr->numOfChildren + 1) * sizeof(XML_ELEMENT));

/* Copy the entry to the new place */
pParent->pChildrenArr->childrenArray[pParent->pChildrenArr->numOfChildren] = *pChild;

/* One more child now */
pParent->pChildrenArr->numOfChildren++;
```

**Edit:** It seems you already have an allocated array with a maximum number of entries, then you don't have to reallocate:

```
if (pParent->pChildrenArr->numOfChildren < pParent->pChildrenArr->maxNumOfChildren)
{
    pParent->pChildrenArr->childrenArray[pParent->pChildrenArr->numOfChildren] = *pChild;
    pParent->pChildrenArr->numOfChildren++;
}
```

If you want to increase the size of the array when needed, you have to combine these two methods:

```
PCHILDREN_ARR pArray = pParent->pChildrenArr;

if (pArray->numOfChildren >= pArray->maxNumOfChildren)
{
    /* We need to reallocate */
    pArray->maxNumOfChildren += 5;

    pArray->childrenArray = realloc(pArray->childrenArray,
                                    pArray->maxNumOfChildren * sizeof(XML_ELEMENT));
}

pArray->childrenArray[pArray->numOfChildren++] = *pChild;
```

Comment: but how can i do arr[x] ? i've allocated dynamically the childrenArray .. so when I do childrenArra[x] it's meaningless no? pChild is alreay an allocated pointer to the needed struct

Comment: and I'm using resalloc, just didn't write it cause this wasn't the main problem so I didn't want to trash this page :)